# How do I prevent HTTP_REFERER from being overwritten

Tags: php, html, wordpress, session, http-referer

Before the `<html>` tag in the `header.php` file of my WordPress site I have the following code:

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['refererurl'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

?>
```

To test the above code, I placed the following code in the front-page.php file (and it works):

```
<?php
    echo $_SESSION['refererurl'];
?>
```

I'm doing this because I want to track the referrer URL that led a visitor to my site from an external site (for goal tracking purposes). The problem is that `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` resets on page-load, so while the information is useful when a visitor first lands on my website, it's overwritten whenever the visitor navigates further into my site.

Is there any way to store the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` when a visitor first arrives at my site from an external site for as long as the visitor is on my site?

I'm rather new to PHP at this level, so please excuse my lack of experience. I'm storing `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in a session simply because that's what I've gathered would work based on some quick research into sessions and cookies.

Comment: Check if the referrer contains your domain name, and ignore it if it does?

Comment: I'll ultimately need to post this information to a form, so in one way or another I need the initial value to be recorded for the duration of the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple - only set it **if** it isn't already set.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['refererurl'])) {
    $_SESSION['refererurl'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
```

Comment: You may also want to use `parse_url` on `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to detect and ignore referrers from your own site's domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `$_SESSION['refererurl']` is already set and simply don't override it :-)

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['refererurl'])) {
    $_SESSION['refererurl'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
```

You might also want to check if the referer is empty before trying to assign it:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !isset($_SESSION['refererurl'])) {
    $_SESSION['refererurl'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
```